# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in Z:\home\ip.ru\www\ip.php on line 39

Tags: php

После запуска кода в браузере пишется следущее: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in Z:\home\ip.ru\www\ip.php on line 39. В чем ошибка если там стоит ";", а все скобки закрыты? Вот код:
https://github.com/1yaroslav/ip.php/blob/main/ip.php
. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вы или `echo` функцией используйте полностью (конкатенация внутри скобок), или уберите скобки и используйте как языковую конструкцию.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar после того как я убрал все скобки появилось это: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in Z:\home\ip.ru\www\ip.php on line 39

Comment: А если отразить `;` в `:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`? (заменить на `\;`)

Comment: @t.forward_100 вы не закрыли скобку после br, и у вас лишняя операторная скобка после fclose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"unexpected ';'" переводится как "неожиданная ';'". То есть парсер ожидает чего-то другое, а не точку с запятой. Если посчитать скобки в этой строке, то становится понятно чего он ожидает.

Чтобы не делать таких ошибок можно иначе форматировать код или использовать вспомогательные переменные:

```
echo (
    str_replace(
        ":", ":&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", fgets($sock, 128)
    ) . "<br>";
// <-- сразу видно, что скобку не закрыли
```

```
$data = fgets ($sock, 128);
$msg = str_replace(":", ":&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $data);
echo ($msg . "<br>"; // <-- тоже всё понятно
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Только теперь  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in Z:\home\ip.ru\www\ip.php on line 46

Comment: А когда я добавляю { получается очень много ошибок:

Comment: https://ibb.co/wKGRSrD

Comment: @t.forward_100 вы не должны просто добавлять или удалять скобки. Разберитесь какая скобка к чему относится.  Измените форматирование (добавьте и уберите отступы) кода так, чтобы открывающие и закрывающие скобки оказались на одной вертикали. Вы сразу увидите, что не так. Двигайтесь по строчке с начала до конца.